# Get an absolute link as string from an existing link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, absolute-path

I am trying to create something similar to the results of a google-search.
It should look like this:

```
h2 Some heading
span www.somelink.com
span Here comes a text. Hello World.
a www.somelink.com (This is an actual link)
```

My View looks like this:

```
h1 Results
  - @i = 0
  - @obj.each do |o|
    = li
        h2 = o
        span = link_to o, o_path
        span = @description[@i]
        span = (link_to o, o_path).to_str
        - @i = @i + 1
```

@description is an Array of 4 elements that each contain a description for the @obj element.
The outcome of
    span = (link_to o, o_path).to_str
looks like:

`<a href="/somelink">Some Text</a>`
I only want it to show
`localhost:3000/somelink`

The work to be done here is:

- Make the link an absolute link
- Filter out only what comes after href

Is this somehow possible without much effort? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_url` instead of `_path`. `url` with return the full URL and `path` the absolute path to your linked page, from your current page.

```
h1 Results
  - @i = 0
  = ul
  - @obj.each do |o|
    = li
      h2 = o
      span = link_to o, o_url
      span = @description[@i]
      span = (link_to o, o_path).to_str
      - @i = @i + 1
```

According to [the official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can call your URL Helper like this:

```
- @obj.each do |o|
  # etc.
    span = o_url
```

A better example with User:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = user_url(user.id) # should return the full path
  = user_path(user.id) # should return the relative path
```